# How to add rows in merged fusion tables?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using fusion tables to load data on google map using google map api v3.  I have merged that fusion table with state,county boundaries so I can have map loaded with those boundaries. What is the better way to manage merged fusion table?  There is a fusion table API but looks like it doesn't let to add new row in merged fusion table.  I am sure that people need to add new row in fusion table.  I was wondering how it can be managed?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation it is [not possible to add rows or columns to a merged table](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#tableDef).

As for the rows it's very easy to circumvent this limitation, because you can simply add new rows to the *base tables* that your merged tables is based on.